# Bex Error on reading from a file in C

Tags: c, windows-7-x64

In file count.c, program reads a string from a file and then counts the total number of characters given in the file. Following are the lines of code in file count.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
#define max 1000
{
    char c, inpt[max];
    int i;
    for (i=0; (c=getchar()) !='\n'; ++i){
        inpt[i]=c;
    }
    printf("Count is %d. ",i);
}
```

Code compiles successfully without any error messages but when I run command:

```
    count.exe < Rehan.txt
```

Program crashes saying `'count.exe has stopped working'`.

Problem details are:

```
    Problem signature:
    Problem Event Name: BEX
    Application Name:   count.exe
    Application Version:    0.0.0.0
    Application Timestamp:  53e5d5d5
    Fault Module Name:  StackHash_e98d
    Fault Module Version:   0.0.0.0
    Fault Module Timestamp: 00000000
    Exception Offset:   ffffffff
    Exception Code: c0000005
    Exception Data: 00000008
    OS Version: 6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1
    Locale ID:  1033
    Additional Information 1:   e98d
    Additional Information 2:   e98dfca8bcf81bc1740adb135579ad53
    Additional Information 3:   6eab
    Additional Information 4:   6eabdd9e0dc94904be3b39a1c0583635
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your file has a single line, your program will loop forever, also, check for `i < max - 1`, try:

```
for (i = 0; i < (max - 1) && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i)
{
    inpt[i] = c;
}
```

And what about the trailing 0? NUL terminate `inpt` if you want a valid string:

```
inpt[i] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a buffer overflow exception. Apparently Rehan.txt is a file without a `'\n'` character in the first 1000 characters, so the loop tries to write `inpt[i]` for values of `i` larger than 999. You can prevent this from happening by checking for EOF instead, as well as a `i < 1000` condition, so that you don't get the same error for files that are larger than your buffer.

Finally, if that's all this program needs to do, consider eliminating `inpt` altogether. Your code writes to this buffer but doesn't read from it.

Comment: `i < 1000` isn't giving the correct output while EOF is. Thanks for the clear explanation.

Answer (score 1):

1.- The file has no \n

2.- The file length is longer than 1000

You should take care the program doesn't arrive to the end of file.

Your program remade.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
#define max 1000
{
    char c, inpt[max];
    int i;
    bool bEnd=false;
    for (i=0; !bEnd; i++)
    {
        c=getchar();
        if(c=='\n' || c==EOF)
        {
            inpt[i]=0;
            bEnd=true;
        }
        else
        {
            inpt[i]=c;
        }
    }
    printf("Count is %d. ",i);
}
```